# Bootstrap responsive not working after including Viewport meta

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says the responsive feature of Bootstrap 3.0 is not working on any mobile device (Android, iPad) in my website. It works perfectly in chrome and firefox by making the window smaller.

I know a common problem is forgetting to include the 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
but I already have it inside my header tag like this:

**Full HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
<title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

**Custom CSS Code**

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Am I missing something else? I have found a lot of posts related to this problem but all seem to be solved by adding the meta tag.

I even tried with two default templates from getbootstrap.com adding the meta tag manually and other meta tags found on other websites but it wont work. Any idea why?

Also I already added the root for the javascript functions at the bottom of the code (not sure if this helps but it enabled the slide menu coming from the 3 line button of the responsive feature).

[**Website**](http://www.windfury.net)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but when you inspect via Firebug or whatever, are there any javascript errors, network errors, i.e. missing files? Are you running https and pulling files http? On that same device does getbootstrap.com look fine?

Comment: show us an example of your divs and rows, I suspect the issue may be with your classes

Comment: I inspected it via Firebug and it seems just fine, at least for me (just used it a couple times). I dont know what you mean by running https and pulling http :/ I am new on this website thing. And yes in that same device Bootstrap templates looks fine (even the same one im using so it must be something inside my code).

Comment: I am just running a default template so all my divs and rows are the same as the example on getbootstrap. You can find my website here [link](http://windfury.net)

Comment: Can you make your site NOT run in an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site pulls in `http://sales-person-fish-27838.bitballoon.com/` via an iframe. Go directly there and it works fine. What host or how are you loading your content.

Comment: You are right, it works perfectly if I go directly to the original adress.

I am using https://www.bitballoon.com/ is a drag & drop hosting website. I got the windfury.net domain name throught godaddy.com there I just enabled a masked forwarding function on godaddy's website admin panel. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: probably need to update stuff in the settings  ask bitballoon

Comment: I was using that hosting just as temporal resource, I will get the hosting with godaddys to avoid forwarding. That will fix it.